# Need explanation on linker (ld) error "Absolute addressing .. not allowed in slidable image"

Tags: xcode, gcc, linker-errors, ld

I've created "bundle" xcode target and linked it against several static libs. I got "Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) used in ... from ... not allowed in slidable image. Use '-read_only_relocs suppress' to enable text relocs. After I've added -read_only_relocs suppress to Other Linker Flags, target builds just fine, but I don't have any clue about what was wrong and how that flag fixed it. Can somebody, please, explain all that stuff to me?

Answer (score 1):

You should uncheck "Generate Position Dependent Code" in your target build settings.

Answer (score 0):

use Xcode 4.1 or before and it's work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you answer an older question such as this, you need to provide an answer that stands out.  Your answer really doesn't provide any explanation about what is going on — in particular, it does not attempt to explain what the `-read_only_relocs_suppress` flag actually does.